# Android Studio not installing plugin's or importing settings

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android, android-studio-2.1

I'm trying to install the Fabric plugin with Crashlytics for Android Studio 2.1. Every time I install it, after restarting, the plugin no longer exists. I've tried installing it directly from disk with the zip file, and separately using just the jar. I thought maybe it's my installation, so I did a clean wipe of Android Studio and installed it from scratch with no custom settings with a brand new test app. No matter what I do I can't seem to get the thing to stay in. Specifically, it says installed and needs to restart, but it just doesn't even show up after the restart, not even disabled. No error messages show up (not sure where else I would look other than popup's or console).

I then tried installing any random plugin I could find in the basic repositories. None of them will stay past the restart. Given that this is a clean install, I have no idea what else to look for. Win 7/64

Anyone have any idea why it won't stick? As a separate note, I have Android Studio 2.1 on a different computer (Win10/64) and the plugin installed and works fine there. I'm still a bit new to the IntelliJ interface, so I'm not sure if there's some setting I'm missing...but I haven't found any SO or other references to point me in any viable direction...

UPDATE:

I still have no idea why it's not installing plugin's properly, but I was able to bypass it. It seems the plugin config data was being added to the appropriate config files (aka `.AndroidStudio/config/plugins/availables.xml`), but the actual core plugin was not. So I manually added the contents of the zip file (mainly the folder `CrashlyticsPlugin` to the `/config/plugins/` directory. Once I restarted again, it picked it up and works just fine.

Whatever the problem is, it's affecting import of any settings as well. The settings files are being imported and stored temporarily in `/system/plugins`, but are not being copied afterwards into the appropriate location in `/config/`. For example, I was trying to import a custom theme. AS says it imported and requires restart, but it never shows up as an option. In the `/config/colors` path, the file is missing. I manually copied the `theme.xml` file to that path and changed the extension to `.icls`, restarted and finally it showed up.

So still hoping someone can tell me why my installation got all crazy...but at least I can make it work for the time being...

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Android Studio 2.1.1. Unzipping the file in `system/plugins/` to `config/plugins/` worked for me. I happen to have custom settings for `idea.config.path` and `idea.system.path` (to keep files off of my NFS home directory) - not sure if that's part of the problem.